# Sudden PHP parse error on RHEL

Tags: php, linux, rhel

I have various PHP files, none of which have been modified prior to the app working and it breaking. My problem is that for some reason, these files are suddenly throwing PHP parse errors for things like 'unexpected' square brackets in seemingly random places throughout the file, but upon manually checking the file, the syntax is correct.

The only thing I did that could have 'altered' the files would be various chmod operations to change the permissions. But how/why would this change the actual content of the files?

The files are called on boot just as they always have been, and have worked fine in the past, up until the recent chmod changes.

Is this permanent, or will I just have to restore my system from an earlier time?

RHEL 6.5, PHP 5.4.

Edit:

Example of the error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/ptc/CRM-dev/tools/init on line 122
```

What's on line 122:

```
$files = [];
```

Another example:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /var/ptc/CRM-dev/vendor/react/promise/src/functions.php on line 68
```

What's on line 68:

```
 return resolve([]);
```

But these files themselves haven't been changed (as far as I'm aware), and the syntax looks correct.

phpinfo() gives 5.4.39, which is the same as when running php -v on the server.

Comment: How would we be able to tell without seeing the code?

Comment: there can be a lot of reason. Give us an example of a line that causes an error. here is a possibility: 'mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)['r']'

Comment: "seemingly random places" - you mean seemingly random *to you*? maybe not for us. show an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP version has been changed then it may be stumbling on the PHP 5.4 square bracket array syntax.

Use `phpinfo();` to be sure that the PHP version running the web server is the same as the one you're using on the CLI.